# soap header not parsing in spring soap endpoint

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd

```
<soapenv:Header>
<auth:Authentication xmlns:auth="https://memorynotfound.com/security">
     <auth:username>username</auth:username>
     <auth:password>password</auth:password>
  </auth:Authentication>
</soapenv:Header>
```

When I handle request header in mine endpoint method it couldn't work. But working when I set small letter 'a' in authentication.
Following is end point snippet :

`@RequestPayload GetStudentRequest request, @SoapHeader("{" + Authentication.AUTH_NS + "}authentication") SoapHeaderElement auth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following snippet `@annotation` value on top of the header class. Hope it helps

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.gooogle.com", name = "Authentication")
public class Authentication{
.....
}
```